# Rails 4 Params Permit array of objects with arrays as values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a check_box_tag that returns me a permission object that I can't seem to permit.
I have checked on StackOverflow and tried a few things but since I am new to coding and params I can't get to make it work.

The params look like this:
`"product_builder_permissions"=>[{"1"=>["1"], "2"=>["1"], "6"=>["42", "59"]}]`

with the key of the nested hash being the id of the product builder and the values in the array the object id to which those builders have access to.

If I change a bit my HTML and get one key for each builder, I am able to whitelist with something such as `params.permit(
product_builder_permissions1: [])
params.permit(
product_builder_permissions1: [])`
etc. 
which is inefficient.

I am trying to work with something like `params.permit(product_builder_permissions:[0])` I only whitelist the key and value at the first level but not what's nested since I get
`{"product_builder_permissions"=>[{}]}`

I also tried something like 
`params.permit(product_builder_permissions:[0][:builder_id.to_s.to_i, :maker_id.to_s.to_i])` to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm taking a look at your question. As I do that and out of curiosity, are you using `product_builder_permissions` for mass assignment? Or, are you further processing those values somehow? If the latter, using strong parameters may not be the route to go, as they are meant for protecting attributes from end-user assignment. [This makes Action Controller parameters forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignment until they have been explicitly enumerated.](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

Comment: thanks a lot, @jvillian for your swift response.

The view displays a table with:
- builders (like shirt, pants etc.)
- makers (like suppliers)

For each of those there is a check_box_tag. On submitting the form, I get in the params product_builder_permissions that maps all the checked items.

E.g. product_builder_permissions"=>[{"1"=>["1"]}] means builder 1 gets access to maker 1.

Then, I iterate through it and for the current brand in the controller I create or destroy the permission which is a join between brand, maker and builder.

Thanks for the link, I will check it now.

Comment: Given that you're not doing mass assignment, I suggest you skip the heartache of strong parameters and just manipulate the parameters directly.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're not doing mass assignment, I suggest you skip the heartache of strong parameters and just manipulate the parameters directly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you end up doing?

Comment: Hey @jvillian! Since we're migrating to 5.2, my lead dev told me in 5+ you have to handle strong params. We tried a few things but since it was not successful he's got the task in his hands now. As soon as I get an answer I'll post it!

Comment: Well, that's an interesting statement. I have a bunch of 5+ rails applications where I use/manipulate params (outside of mass assignment) without using strong params. So, my direct experience is not consistent with your lead dev's statement. But, you know, who am I to say?

Comment: Oh that's weird indeed. I'll keep you posted if/when he gets back to me.